# laravel mail sending problem with mail driver on real server

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4, laravel-mail

I'm using laravel 5.4 and for mail i use mail driver to real server mail hosting.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mail.xxx.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxx
```

with this config in local not send email but send in server. why?

I try the all options for mail config but not send.

### i did ( but not work )

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.xxx.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxx

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.xxx.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxx

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.xxx.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxx

MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mail.xxx.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxx
```

they don't work. how can i send an email from local ?

Comment: Have you configure your gmail account , turn on  your allow access of your account ?

Comment: I dont use gmail for mail server. I use a webmail server

Answer (score 0):

Steps to configure **Gmail:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxx@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxx
```

For app password Read Under the Section [How to generate an App password:](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)
You may not be able to create an App password for [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255).

Steps to configure **Mailtrap:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxx
```

For username and password Go to Inbox page: https://mailtrap.io/inboxes Click on Demo Inbox link and you will see username and password will be something like this:    `"username" => "b8f25cb615a7b3", "password" => "8218789886905f",` Copy this username and password and set in the configuration

After completion of `.env` edit don't forget to clear a cache: `php artisan config:cache`